# objects and strings

Tags: php, object

I was trying to return a set of objects.

But this code gives me the following error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class User could not be converted to string in ...

```
 public function fetchObject($psClassname ="",$paParams =array()){
            $lrResource = $this->mrQueryResource;
            $liResult = null; 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($lrResource,$psClassname,$paParams)){
                $liResult .= $row;     <-this line produces the error
            }
            return $liResult;
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code $row is a an object (you've used mysql_fetch_object), and the .= operator tries to build a string, concatenating $liResult and $row. I believe this behaviour only works if your object implements a [toString method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)

You could return an array of rows using this code:

```
public function fetchObject($psClassname ="",$paParams =array()){
        $lrResource = $this->mrQueryResource;
        $liResult = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($lrResource,$psClassname,$paParams)){
                $liResult[] = $row;
        }
        return $liResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to convert $row to a string (the .= assumes a string is given on the right hand side)